# Error: One or more models did not validate: Django+South, shemamigration generic --auto

Tags: django, migration, django-south

Im trying to run the shemamigration generic --auto

```
    generic.articletocategory: 'article' has a relation with model generic.Article, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
    generic.category: 'articles' is a manually-defined m2m relation through model ArticleToCategory, which does not have foreign keys to Article and Category


class ArticleToCategory(m.Model):    
    article = m.ForeignKey('generic.Article')
    category = m.ForeignKey('generic.Category')

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'generic' 
        db_table = 'articles_to_categories'
        verbose_name_plural = 'ArticlesToCategories'

class Article(m.Model):
    pass


class Category(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, related_name='children')

    # relationships
    articles = m.ManyToManyField('generic.Article', through='generic.ArticleToCategory')
```

### Solved!

the article in the Meta class has `app_label = 'Generic'` instead of `'generic'`

Comment: This question may eventually be closed as too localized, but in the meantime, please add your "solved" comment as an answer, and accept it. This is the standard operating procedure on StackOverflow anytime you find the solution on your own and helps keep StackOverflow clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the article in the Meta class has app_label = 'Generic' instead of 'generic'